# migration files and schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

So my Mac went down and now trying to build my project on my new Mac.  I need to know when running rake `db:migrate` does it look at the `schema.rb` file?

As I am getting

```
Mysql::Error: Table 'myproject_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
```

Even when I run rake `db:migrate:up VERSION=001` which has no reference to users I get the same error?

If it matters my migrations start like

```
001_...
002_...
003_...
20100222171241_...
```

Comment: what happens when you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: How is it that your migration files have `nnn_` *and* `20100222171241..` prefixes? AFAIK, the former is the 'old way' and the latter the 'new way'.

Comment: old project not touched then restarted 1.5 years later.

Comment: When I run rake db:migrate, before and after renaming old migration files with new the naming format, I get Mysql::Error: Table 'myproject_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The migration code generally doesn't look at the schema file. It looks at the names of all the migration files and the database table called `schema_migrations`, and determines which migrations haven't been run yet. (I believe it does dump the schema at the end of running migrations.) Either your missing a migration, or your `schema_migrations` table is out of sync with your database.

After making a backup, you can start to troubleshoot. Do you have a migration that creates the users table? If not, where did it go? If you have it, why isn't it running?

FYI The migrations that start with numbers (eg. `001`) are older versions of migrations. Sometime around 2.2 or 2.3 the names of the migrations were changed to dates, which is what you are seeing in the later migrations.

There may be a problem with the way those first few migrations are named, and they are not being found (I can't remember the migration story when this naming scheme switched). And maybe it tracked the migrations differently back then so there may be some futzing to make it work with the more modern scheme. You can fairly safely rename them following the new scheme, using the datestamp of the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Found it.  Line 14 of my environment.rb config.active_record.observers = :user_observer if I take it out it runs the migrations, then I just put it back after they are run.

Comment: That means you are mentioning you `User` class in the migrations... a risky proposition.